# Need to upgrade DDR2 RAM on HP Desktop

Tags: upgrade, memory

I have this [HP Pavilion Desktop](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00708224&tmp_track_link=ot_faqs/top_issues/en_us/c00708224/loc:4&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=3198175&lang=en). As you can see, that page says the memory speed supported is PC2-4200. It currently has a 512 MB stick - CPU-Z Screenshots:

[image] [image]

However, a crucial.com scan gives [a slightly different report](http://crucial.com/systemscanner/viewscanbyid.aspx?id=5718CFE831D926C3) -  It says the system can support PC2-5300 memory.

So my question is which one should I trust? **I want to upgrade the computer's ram to 2 GB** (the maximum supported), because XP Media Center is giving me problems and I will install Windows 7 on this. PC2-6400 is the most common DDR2 memory I have been able to find here in the market. Will it cause any problems if I install 2 × 1 GB PC2-6400 DDR2 memory sticks (in dual channel) in this computer, (afaik, it will just run at the lower speed of 533 MHz, or whatever the motherboard supports), or do I absolutely need to get PC2-4200 sticks?

Comment: CPU-Z is showing what is installed. Chipsets usually support more than one speed within a technology.

Answer (score 1):

A rather [comprehensive answer from comreviews.com:](http://compreviews.about.com/od/memory/f/FasterRAM.htm)

TLDR:

> If you are intending to use a faster
>   memory module in your computer, here
>   is a summary of the items to consider
>   before purchasing and installing it:
>
> - The memory has to be of **the same
>     technology** (DDR, DDR2 and DDR3 are not
>     cross compatible)
> - The PC must support
>     the **memory module densities** being
>     considered
> - **No unsupported features**
>     like ECC must be present on the module
> - The memory will only be **as fast as
>     that supported by the memory** or as
>     slow as the slowest installed memory
>     module

---

> The answer to this question really is
>   yes and no. If you are talking about a
>   computer for example that uses DDR and
>   you want to use DDR2, it will not
>   work. They use two different clocking
>   technologies that are not compatible
>   within a system. Now, if you are
>   looking at the same type of memory as
>   what is already in the system, then
>   you can buy memory that is faster than
>   the existing memory. Of course, there
>   are always restrictions.
>
> In order for this to work, the memory
>   modules must be of a density that is
>   supported by the computer motherboard.
>   For example, a system that can support
>   1GB modules cannot use a faster 2GB
>   memory module as the system will not
>   recognize it. Similarly, if your
>   motherboard won't support memory with
>   ECC, it won't support faster modules
>   if they have this feature.
>
> The other issue has to do with the
>   speed. Even though they may be faster
>   modules, they will not be running at
>   the faster speed. This can happen in
>   two cases. The first is that the
>   motherboard or processor will not
>   support the faster memory speed. When
>   this happens, the modules will instead
>   be clocked at the fastest speed that
>   they can support. If the modules are
>   installed with some slower ones
>   already installed, the memory system
>   will run at the slowest memory timings
>   and speed.
>
> So, why would you want to install
>   faster memory in a system if it will
>   still run at the slower speed? It has
>   to do with availability and pricing.
>   Often times as memory technology ages,
>   slower modules may drop out of
>   production leaving only faster ones
>   available. Such might be the case with
>   a system that supports PC2700 DDR
>   memory but all you can find is PC3200
>   DDR modules. Memory is considered a
>   commodity and as a result has variable
>   pricing. This can result in situations
>   where a faster memory module might be
>   less expensive than a slower one. If
>   PC2-5400 DDR2 supplies are tight, it
>   might be less expensive to buy a
>   PC2-6400 DDR2 module instead.